# Python And Date Formats

Tags: python, datetime

I have an inherited wxPython application. To my mind it needs a degree of tidying as dates can appear in slightly different formats. An example piece of code is shown below (I have added the 'print' statements:-

```
formattedDate = str(Date.tm_year) + '-' + str(Date.tm_mon) + '-' + str(Date.tm_mday)
print 'formattedDate is >', formattedDate, '<' 
today  = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print 'Today is >', today, '<'
```

which gives an output of:-

```
formattedDate is > 2015-8-14 <
Today is > 2015-08-14 <
```

The formattedDate is based on user input and is a patient's DateOfBirth (added to database). What is puzzling me is why the month is a single digit in one case and two digits in the other. I have gone through my Python books and trawled the net but been unable to find an answer.

Comment: What is `Date.tm_mon` ?

Comment: tm_mon is an attribute of the class time.struct_time. The three values I am using are the year, month and day (of month). It's part of the standard Python library. The formatting inconsistency was throwing me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ass `Date` is of type - `time.struct_time` . This is because `Date.tm_mon` returns the integer representation of the month (of type `int`) and when you convert it to `str` manually you get the amount of digits it has.

An Example -

```
>>> t = time.strptime('2015-8-10','%Y-%m-%d')
>>> t
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=222, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> t.tm_mon
8
>>> type(t.tm_mon)
<class 'int'>
>>> str(t.tm_mon)
'8'
```

When you use `strftime()` with the format `%m` , python correctly formats the month to always be 2 digits, as [documented -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

> %m   -  Month as a decimal number [01,12].

Example -

```
>>> time.strftime('%m')
'08'
```

I would always recommnd you to use `strftime()` to format the date as string, and not create them manually. To format a `time.struct_time` object using `strftime()` you pass the `time.struct_time` object as second argument to `strtime()` , Example -

```
>>> time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d',t)
'2015/08/10'
```

Answer (score 0):

All is ok, acording to documentation:

print time.strftime shows 2 digits

%m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].

And Date.tm_mon - looks like it is custom class/field and it shows one digit value. Check what is Date.tm_mon and how it stores value, maybe it truncates zero

Answer (score 0):

Date.tm_mon is probably an integer and str(8) would print a single digit (no leading zero).

On the other hand %m in time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') always outputs 2 digit month ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)).